# Why do types need to be specified in JSON-LD after the context?

Tags: json, schema.org, json-ld

In JSON-LD the `@type` shows up not just at the top level, but in the `contactPoint` property. Why is it needed if the context is already provided?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  { "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com",
    "contactPoint" : [
      { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
        "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1212",
        "contactType" : "customer service"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Doesn't the parser know from the context and the first `@type` line that we're working with an organization, and so the property `contactPoint` is meant to have that type of object in it? Otherwise, can I rename that property to just `contact` and then specifying the `@type` should inform what it is? The example seems redundant to me. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about how JSON-LD is working here.

Comment: What exactly is the part that seems redundant to you? That the value of the `contactPoint` property has the type `ContactPoint` (i.e., why `"@type": "ContactPoint"` couldn’t be omitted in that case)?

Comment: Yes. Or why type cannot be determined from the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema.org [does not require](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected) which values a property can have. It lists the *expected* values, but authors don’t have to follow that, it’s just a recommendation.

For example, the expected value of the [`contactPoint`](http://schema.org/contactPoint) property is an entity with the [`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint) type. But it’s possible to use a string or a URL value instead (strictly speaking even a `Thing` item, or any other type).

Even if you would always follow the recommendation and use the expected type, it’s still not necessarily clear which type you mean, because

- there are properties that expect one of several types as value (e.g., [`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered) expects `Product` or `Service`)
- a property could expect an addtional type in a future version of Schema.org, and then it would no longer be clear which one you mean
- an expected type of a property could be removed in a future version of Schema.org, but your already published structured data might not make sense with the new expected type

Comment: Mmm... sounds like this is designed to evolve over time with the websites and apps of the internet. That's pretty cool.